# Who would own the copyright to the original character in a freelance commissioned art piece?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I was debating some friends who were very into Dungeons and Dragons (DnD). They created these original characters. One friend commissioned a piece of art for their original character. It was a simple PayPal (or Venmo?) transfer commission. However, I was wondering: does my friend still own the character itself? Or does the artist now own the character or simply the artwork? There was no "Work for Hire" or any contract. Just a conversation and payment and the artwork at the end. We were wondering, say my friend then wishes to...write a poem, novel, or screenplay featuring that character, do they even own the character anymore? Do they still own the character but not the artwork itself? We heavily confused ourselves in this debate so we would love some clarification/input!

Comment: To be clear, you're asking about who owns the character -- not the artistic rendering of the character? Those questions would be analyzed differently from each other.

Comment: Yes apologies I am asking who would own the character itself. For example, let's say after the freelance art was commissioned, if my friend was to write a television pilot screenplay or book of that character -- could the freelance artist object? I am just wondering who owns the character itself really. Not the piece of artwork that was commissioned.

Answer (score 3):

### There's multiple copyrights

#### The Character (description)

Alice has a cool character: Bob the Barbarian. She describes him in an e-mail. That affixes her description of Bob in a tangible matter. Alice owns the sole copyright in that description as far as it is creative and protectable.

#### The Artistic depiction

Charly the Artist draws commissions. They do not fall under *Work for Hire*.

When Alice hired them to draw Bob, he created a *derivative work* of Alice's description. Charly owns a copyright in the artwork, but Alice owns some parts too, because it is a derivative of her text. The two own the copyright **jointly**.

#### The Unprotected elements

Now, here comes the big thing: there's a lot of unprotected elements that make up the character together:

- Ideas. Not copyrightable.
- Scenes a faire. Aka "generic things", that are just standard. If Bob is described as "A blonde hunk of a man" that's pretty much generic and not protected.

Only expressed things that are beyond the unprotectable and which tie it all together create copyrightable character designs.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks this is interesting! So just because the freelance artist drew a picture of the character, it doesn't mean they own that character? So in this case, the artist does not own the character of "Bob the Barbarian". However, they do own that photo they drew and can object if my friend used Bob in commercial works. However, let's say my friend wrote a screenplay/book about Bob the Barbarian but did not used that artwork -- could the artist still object?

Comment: The artist owns nothing in the original description. He could object the use of his work, not Alice's.

Comment: I think I understand! Thank you so much. So if Alice wrote a book and wanted to publish it and tried to use this piece of art; then that would be a problem. However, if Alice simply wrote a book and never showed the artwork in her commercial item, then there is nothing there for the artist to object to?

Comment: @randomthoughts11 yes. If Alice does want illustrations of the character to use in the book, the best course of action (if the original artist will not permit this use) would be to commission another artist using the same (or a similar) description, and make a suitable license part of the agreement with the second artist. Ideally, this artist should not have seen the original art.